# getting find in page working on mobile browsers?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have made a search box to search around the page for words and staff. However, it's not working for mobile browsers. The main reason I need it is for mobile browsers, because you can't use ctrl-f in them.

Can anyone tell what's going wrong?

Here's my Javascript code:

```
var TRange=null;

function findString (str) {
    if (parseInt(navigator.appVersion)<4) return;
    var strFound;
    if (window.find) {

        // CODE FOR BROWSERS THAT SUPPORT window.find

        strFound=self.find(str);
        if (!strFound) {
             strFound=self.find(str,0,1);
             while (self.find(str,0,1)) continue;
        }
    }
    else if (navigator.appName.indexOf("Microsoft")!=-1) {

        // EXPLORER-SPECIFIC CODE

        if (TRange!=null) {
            TRange.collapse(false);
            strFound=TRange.findText(str);
            if (strFound) TRange.select();
        }
        if (TRange==null || strFound==0) {
            TRange=self.document.body.createTextRange();
            strFound=TRange.findText(str);
            if (strFound) TRange.select();
        }
    }
    else if (navigator.appName=="Opera") {
        alert ("Opera browsers not supported, sorry...")
        return;
    }
    if (!strFound) alert ("String '"+str+"' not found!")
        return;
    }
```

Comment: What's the problem with it? What's it showing / missing / errors?

Comment: Post a jsFiddle and some HTML.

Comment: the problem that it's not working on the mobile browsers it's just giving that the text i'm trying to search for is not found !! but it's working perfect on the computer browsers !!

Comment: did you find any solution @MahmoudAhmed